nslookup shows same IP address for any domain name
Every time I nslookup a domain name, I get these same ip addresses "185.38.109.109" which point to a "Czechia". Can someone help me with this issue?
enter image description here

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Something is adding ".domain.name" to the end of all your DNS queries. In command prompt, run ipconfig, and look for a line that says Connection-specific DNS Suffix: domain.name. You can remove it by following the steps here: https://superuser.com/questions/1507445/delete-and-add-entries-to-dns-suffixes

Thanks, it was help full and worked.
